# derive image path to load using javascript objects from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, object, dom-manipulation

i am trying to learn some javascript at the moment and wanted to practice a little form manipulation stuff, doing my own awesome pizzaconfigurator(kinda like the one on papa joes) - hoped you could guide me a little on the process

html(stripped down to the important parts):

```
<input type="radio" name="crust" value="crust"  class="userChoice" onclick="parameter1(this.value)" checked>Pizza with normal crust.</input>
<input type="radio" name="crust" value="cheesycrust"  class="userChoice" onclick="parameter1(this.value)">Pizza with cheese in the crust.</input>

<h2>Pizza Topping:</h2>
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="margarita" onclick="parameter2(this.value)">tomato sauce and cheese
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="funghi" onclick="parameter2(this.value)">tomato sauce, cheese and mushrooms
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="tonno" onclick="parameter2(this.value)">tomato sauce, cheese and tuna
<input type="radio" name="pizzaType" value="alcapone" onclick="parameter2(this.value)">tomato sauce, cheese, bacon, salami and anchovis 
......

<h2>Size:</h2>
    <select id="size" onChange="parameter3(this.value)">
        <option value="1">normal</option>
        <option value="2">family size</option>
     </select>

<span id="checkMyOrder"></span>
```

javascript:

```
var pizzaConfigurator = {
path: parameter1 + parameter2 + parameter3 +".jpeg",
parameter1: function (value1) {
    this.parameter1 = value1;
},
parameter2: function (value2) {
    this.parameter2 = value2;
},
parameter3: function (value3) {
    switch(value3) {
        case "1": this.parameter3 = value3;
        break;
        case "2": this.parameter3 = value3;
        break;
        default:
        alert("Please select size.");
        break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

so where i am really stuck now is, how would i return the values of all my choices in one final variable to pass it into a function would later on fill my checkOrder or dynamically load a "*pizza-crust*-*pizzaType*-*size*.jpeg"?

am i even on the right track?
i tried to model this roughly after the codeacademy javascript tutorial for the cash register

could this be done easier in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model looks very nice for someone just started Javascript.

The main problems here are:

- You can't call function like `parameter2(this.value)` directly because it's inside  pizzaConfigurator object, it needs to be `pizzaConfigurator.parameter2`
- `This` refers to the function it's being called, so it will never get value from `this.parameter3`, read [Scope and this in JavaScript](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/) for more deatails

Here is a working version I tried to write similar to your code style : http://jsfiddle.net/W48Xe/5/

And here is a JQuery demo (http://jsfiddle.net/sJVaw/2/) that gets the same job done (not necessary good for learning though)

Further reading suggested: [The case for object literals over self executing functions for modular javascript](http://mattandre.ws/2012/12/object-literals-vs-self-executing-functions-for-modular-javascript/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Haha, thanks for the compliment first but I guess the credit goes to codeacademy - so they obviously taught me well. :)

In case i wanted to do further manipulation(e.g.add $$ if family size) would i have to do this in an object or can i also do it in the click event in jQuery?